# Calculation of thermal expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, temperature, computational-physics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

how are the thermal expansion of a solid and the stress tensor related?
\begin{equation}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3N}}\frac{\Delta E_p}{\Delta V}\rho_{H_h}(u)du=\frac{2}{3V}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3N}}E_p\rho_{H_h}(u)du+\frac{1}{6V}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3N}}\sum_{ijk}\Psi_{ijk}r_i^{eq}u_ju_k\rho_{H_h}(u)du
 \end{equation}
this is the average of the diagonal elements of the stress tensor in the limit of infinite number of configurations.
"The second term on the right-hand side  corresponds to the partial derivative of the free energy with respect to volume in the quasiharmonic approximation. The first term
on the right hand side can be identified as a kinetic term using the quantum virial theorem".
In the article I am reading   this is written after showing me the average of the diagonal elements of the stress tensor: "lattice parameters are iteratively modified
until the calculated internal pressure equals the target pressure
within a chosen tolerance (of the order of kbar)"

Answer (score 0):

My idea is this: tensor stress is directly related to the internal pressure of a solid. That is to the force that the neighboring atoms exert each other in relation to a unit of surface. When I heat a solid we can have the phenomenon of thermal expansion: this is connected to the fact that a deformation of the solid takes place which leads to an increase in the interatomic distances and therefore to a decrease in the frequencies of the phonons and a lowering of the energy of the system. For this deformation occurs. Now an increase in interatomic distances implies a decrease in internal pressure. The decrease in internal pressure is due only to the variation of the positions of the atoms in the crystal lattice with the expansion. Given that the stress tensor is also calculated as a variation of the potential energy, it seems to me strongly linked to the internal pressure of the solid. In fact, even the potential energy depends only on the atomic positions in the lattice.
I think this is the meaning of what is written in the article. Obviously, to find the correct parameters of the deformed cell I will have to apply an iterative procedure that leads me to equality between the internal pressure of the solid and the external one (target pressure). This condition is necessary for the solid to be in equilibrium.